# Is there an online convertor from Visual Basic to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, vba, vb6

I am looking for a tool to convert some simple visual basic functions to Javascript. I know that it is generally very difficult task but I need to convert only a simple constructions e.g.

```
dim a
a=1
if a >2 then a=a+1
```

to

```
var a;
a=1;
if(a>2)a=a+1
```

I can do it by hand but a tool similar to [Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) would be great help
I am looking for something very simple so even vb vb.net difference doesn't matter too much. I even have some VB6 functions which I need to have in Javascript. I would like to avoid boring edit/search/replace task.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that doesn't exist. If it does, though, it's horribly broken. C# and VB.NET conversions are possible because they're essentially the same language. JavaScript and VB.NET... not so much. Scope being one of the major obstacles.

Comment: Well, maybe this might work. Convert your VB.NET to C#, and then use https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp? Also, is this VB.NET or VB(A)? I'm inclined to think it's VBA from your title, tags and code sample.

Comment: You've tagged this with both "VBA", which is VB 6 under the hood, and VB.NET, which is a different language with some keyword similarities. Which of these languages is your actual code base in?

Comment: VBA is not "VB6 under the hood" at all.  VBA is a subset of VB's procedural code source to p-code incremental compiler, interpretive engine, and copies some of its COM-oriented OOP model.  But it is true VB.Net has only the most casual connection to either VB or VBA.  I believe the sort of hypertagging we see here is meant to attract attention.

Comment: @BobRiemersma It is not hypertagging I realy work in VB6, VB.NET and Javascript. Code I need to convert is simple so even VBA does not matter. VBscript in Beaner answer is rather more difficult because of missing declarations but still it is great help. I need to convert code snippets (as in example) or simple functions not complex object structure or UI interacting code. The code sample I have written is intentionaly valid in VB6, VB.NET, VBA and VBScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try http://slingfive.com/pages/code/scriptConverter/demo.html. I ran your sample through their trial converter (IE compatible) and it returned

```
var a;
a=1;
if(a >2){ a=a+1

// ============================================================================
// This code converted from VBScript to Javascript by the ScriptConverter tool.
// Use freely.  Please do not redistribute without permission.
// Copyright 2003 Rob Eberhardt - scriptConverter@slingfive.com.
// ============================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing code to vbscript is a bit annoying but search and replace can do it. I am glad that something exists despite all comments that it is not possible.

Comment: I like how this only works in IE. It works though.

Comment: seem broken as to date

Answer (score 2):

A search for "vb.net to javascript" turns up [JSIL - .NET to JavaScript compiler](http://jsil.org). Is that what you want? Or maybe http://jsc.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: It is very nice but I need something less complex. Just paste a short snippet and get it converted. Thank you very much I don't even dreamed about something like this.

Comment: I'm late to this party, but if anyone is interested, there is a live example page that converts C# to Javascript here (I didn't test it):

http://jsil.org/try/